# ClassNotFoundException for com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

My code is returning the above error, along with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/ResultSet 
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet <br><br>
```

The place where is the error is occuring is at this line of code:

```
ResultSet rt = (ResultSet) ps.executeQuery();
```

I have checked to make sure I've imported the jar file correctly and that it is in the build and class paths appropriately, and that the run configuration is as it should be. Further code:

```
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,USER,PASS);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
```

A note: This error is only occuring when another machine attempts to the run the jar file which contains this code. It's not happening on Eclipse on the local machine I'm working on.

Comment: Try casting to a `java.sql.ResultSet` instead of a msyql one. The change would be in your import at the top of the file. The java interface is more generic, and doesn't couple your code to mysql, or worse, a specific driver implementation.of mysql.

Comment: What class is JDBC_DRIVER?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann casting to java.sql.ResultSet worked. Thank you!

Comment: So you accidentally imported the wrong `ResultSet`, i.e. `com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet` when you intended to import [`java.sql.ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)? Wasn't a cast problem, and if you remove the unnecessary cast, it still works? Both cast to `ResultSet` and cast to `Connection`?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann There is no need to cast to `java.sql.ResultSet`, as the return value already **is** a `java.sql.ResultSet`

Comment: Yes, that's correct I imported the wrong ResultSet. I'm curious though, if anyone is willing to take the time to explain, why `com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet` is incorrect but `java.sql.ResultSet` isn't? Thanks!

Comment: And removing the cast, the code works. I suppose I don't understand how it could run on my machine but not another, however.